Successfully installed neovim flutter-tools.nvim plugin not loading on opening Flutter project dart files. What can I do?
Had problems loading the akinsho/flutter-tools.nvim plugin, even though it was properly installed (and re-installed). Made explicit the path to the flutter sdk and, still no load. Guessing it had to with file recognition, but how do you deal with plugin file association errors in neovim? I learned the very simple solution. It works perfectly now.

Simply add ft = "dart" to the plugin install to fix an apparently missing file association. This automatically loaded the flutter-tools.nvim plugin as it should have.
{
    "akinsho/flutter-tools.nvim",
      dependencies = { "nvim-lua/plenary.nvim" },
      config = function()
        require("flutter-tools").setup {}
      end,
      ft = "dart",
},

It's better than manually loading the plugin, but you can do that too with Lazy load command:
:Lazy load flutter-tools.nvim

